# Rotating screen while adding tabs clear newly added tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, android-app

This only clears tags added before pressing "done". 
To reproduce :

1. Create a new question
2. Go to tags selection
3. Select tag
4. Rotate screen

Android 6.0.1

Nexus 5

Version 1.0.83